# Trigger segue programmatically on watchOS

Tags: ios, swift3, apple-watch, watchos-3

I'm working on a watchOS 3 app.

I have a segue hooked up to a button and it is working correctly. Now I want to trigger it programmatically.

Upon receiving a message from the phone, I want to navigate the watch to a specific view, but I can't seem to call `self.performSegue` method via WatchKit.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In WatchKit you cannot perform a segue programmatically. Instead you need to use [`pushController(withName:context:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/watchkit/wkinterfacecontroller/1619532-pushcontroller), [`presentController(withName:context:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/watchkit/wkinterfacecontroller/1619560-presentcontroller) or [`presentController(withNames:contexts:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/watchkit/wkinterfacecontroller/1619561-presentcontroller).

Make sure to set identifiers for your WKInterfaceControllers in InterfaceBuilder.

If you need to pass data to controllers, have a look at [`contextForSegue(withIdentifier: String)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/watchkit/wkinterfacecontroller/1619522-contextforsegue)
 and [`contextsForSegue(withIdentifier: String)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/watchkit/wkinterfacecontroller/1619533-contextsforsegue)

Answer (score 3):

You are able to perform a segue programmatically now.

> Alternatively, you can programmatically initiate the push transition by calling the pushController(withName:context:)

[source](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/storyboard_elements/building_watchos_app_interfaces_using_the_storyboard/navigating_between_scenes)

e.g

```
@IBAction func buttonTapped() {
    pushController(withName: "identifierOfNextInterfaceController", context: nil)
}
```